# Async/await does not wait for database query before moving on

Tags: javascript, promise

Below piece of code does not wait for the database query to finish before print out the console.log and I have no idea why. It is confirmed that data exists.

```
const document = await this.database.find({ id: payload.user.id }).sort({ postedAt: 1 }).limit(1).exec((error: any, document: any) => {
      (error) ? error : document;
    });

console.log('Document: ', document);
```

Thank you!

Comment: try removing the .exec, .find() already returns a promise

Comment: You have no `return` statement in the last callback function, so what do you expect to assign to `document`?

Comment: if `this.database.find({ id: payload.user.id }).sort({ postedAt: 1 }).limit(1).exec` doesn't return a Promise, then awaiting it is meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. Is there a way to make it cleaner? Thanks:

```
    const document = () => new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      this.database.find({ id: payload.user.id }).sort({ postedAt: 1 }).limit(1).exec((error: any, document: any) => {
        (error) ? reject(error) : resolve(document);
      });
    }) 

    const x = await document().then((results: any) => {
      console.log('Results: ', results);
      return results;
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
      return false;
    });

    console.log('Doc: ', x);
```